# Get the right node from duplicates xml with NSXML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios, nsxml

I'm trying to us NSXML to parse a user's channel from youtube. Parsing works ok, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the link from any specific movie as their are 5 exact the same nodes as following:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLleTDikufefbk&amp;feature=youtube_gdata" /> 
<link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/vLleTDikededubk/responses" /> 
<link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/vLlededTDikubk/related" /> 
<link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#mobile" type="text/html" href="http://m.youtube.com/details?v=vLldedeeTDikubk" /> 
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/node/uploads/vLlgrgreTDikubk" />
```

I've figured out how to get the attribute href from the node link. But since their are 5 different links I don't know how to only select the first one. Anyone got an idea?

Thnx you guys!!!

Comment: Found the solution already. I'll check if the link node has an attribute with alternate in it. If it does it has the right link node. Here is the code:

    NSMutableArray *link;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"])
    
    if (!link)
        link = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *alternate = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"rel"];
    if([alternate isEqualToString:@"alternate"]){
    NSString *href = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];
        alternate = NULL;
    }

Comment: You CAN answer your own question.

Comment: After 8 hours if you have less then 100 points....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution already. I'll check if the link node has an attribute with alternate in it. If it does it has the right link node. Here is the code:

```
NSMutableArray *link; if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]) if (!link) link = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; NSString *alternate = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"rel"]; if([alternate isEqualToString:@"alternate"]){ NSString *href = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"]; alternate = NULL; }
```